# Work with FileMaker Pro FP7 Files

Tags: filemaker

Is it possible to work with FP7 file using the FileMaker ODBC driver without actually needing to have FileMaker installed?

I can't seem to get it to work unless I have FileMaker open, with the database file opened.

I periodically need to export an FP7 file to somebody who is only willing to accept FP7 files because of "The Process".

Comment: Is the file hosted on FileMaker server? If so, is it regular server or server advanced? If not, can you set up a shutdown script to do the export you need every time the file is modified and closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The only way not to open FileMaker itself is to have the file permanently open on FileMaker server and ODBC from there, but you'll need the most expensive Advanced server for this.

On the other hand FileMaker can import other formats (CSV, TSV, Excel) and has its own XML format, so you can use these formats. (Unless you're sending binary data in container fields, in which case FP7 is the only choice.)

Comment: Argh, I was afraid of that. Unfortunately FP7 is the only option here, and not because of it's contents.